# Replacing a string without using regular expression in netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

Is there any way to replace a string in netezza sql without using regular expression function (i.e. regexp_replace())
eg:
replace('perfect','fect','fume')

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have the SQL Extensions Toolkit installed then you can use:

```
select sql_functions..replace('prefect', 'fect', 'fume')
```

Comment: I dont have any toolkit installed. Is there anyother way. I want to achieve this without toolkit..   Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Without the SQL Extensions Toolkit you can just use `substr` and `instr` functions.  You may have to run them multiple times depending on the recurrence of the string in question.  Below is an example:

```
    select substr(a.txt,1,instr(a.txt,'fect')-1)
          ||'fume'
          ||substr(a.txt,instr(a.txt,'fect')+length('fect'),255)
    from (select 'perfect' as txt) a
```

Comment: what does `||substr(a.txt,instr(a.txt,'fect')+length('fect'),255)` do? Query already returns "perfume" without this.

Comment: If the original string was `perfect chanel no 5` the extra piece would return `perfume chanel no 5`